# what is the order for jquery in head tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using two different plugins of Jquery copied from different sites one is for datepicker in asp.net and second is for autocomplete textbox
but only  the files and code i paste right before the end of the head  tag it works

Datepicker files and js Code

```
  <link href="css/jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
```

when i put these lines at the end of head it works

and this is autocmplete textbox files

```
 <link href="../SearchBoxCss/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../SearchBoxCss/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="../SearchBoxJS/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../SearchBoxJS/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){

        $('#<%= txtmoviename.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "WebService.asmx/GetFilmNames",
                    data: "{ 'FilmName': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    type: "POST",
                      dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        response(result.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                    }
                });
            }


        }); 

    });

</script>
```

basically both are working but not at the same time...

Comment: so basically there isn't a problem, right?
also, it should make no difference in which order you load jquery plugins

Comment: The problem is only one plugin working at a time ..The one i put in the end of the head tag

Comment: when i write datepicker files in the end only date picker works but not autocomplete but when i write auto complete in the end... only autocomplete works date picker doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `duplicate` references for `Jquery library` remove one and both should work.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
```

And

```
<script src="../SearchBoxJS/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Remove one of them i would recommend to remove first because it is being referenced from internet and it may load slow and cause errors.

Comment: I would love to but my reputation isn't enough to mark an answer..
Sorry!

Comment: it says VoteUp requires 15 reputation nd i've 11 yet 
Is voting up considers like an accepted answer or is there any specific option?
I'm voting your question up right now

Comment: @ShaikhNomanNasir No there is an option which show tick sign just click that vote up is not accept. Accept is something else  there would be a Tick sign under my answer click on that.

Comment: sir I've added you facebook with the same name ' shaikh noman nasir' kindly accept the request if it is okay with you! 
and don't worry i won't bother much :D